# ASP.NET Html.TextAreaFor auto resize when writing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, razor

i need to automatically resize ASP.NET Html.TextAreaFor when i'm writing into it. Is there a simple way to do it without any additional libraries(i already use jquery 2 and it needs to work on ff, chrome, ie9+) ? I was looking through old threads, but none of that was working for me. My code is:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.mySummary, new { id = "mySummary" })
```

Comment: you can use jquery.autogrow

Comment: I found AUTOGROW TEXTAREA PLUGIN 3.0, also found some facebook plugin ripoff, all worked really buggy, sometimes not resizing, resizing way too late or way to soon... Is there a good and reliable library for that ?